# Facing an error with FROM syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've just make some complex (yeah, in my pov as a new player in mysql) query in mysql, that include sub-select to add custom field. Okey, lets just view the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cm_reg__`.`TGL`, `cm_reg__`.`JAM`, `cm_reg__`.`ASR`, `cm_reg__`.`CM`, `c_pst`.`NAMA`, `c_pst`.`SEX`, `c_pst`.`AGAMA`, `c_pst`.`EDU`, `c_pst`.`PKJ`, `c_pst`.`ALAMAT`, `c_pst`.`WILAYAH`, `cm_reg__`.`UMUR`, `cm_reg__`.`ASAL`, `cm_reg__`.`NO`, `cm_reg__`.`DR`, `rm_dgs`.`UT`, `cm_reg__`.`DOUT`, `c_pst`.`C_KELUARGA`, `TINDAKAN`, `PENUNJANG`, `IGD`, `TERAPI`, IFNULL(TINDAKAN, `0)` + IFNULL(PENUNJANG, `0)` + IFNULL(IGD, `0)` + IFNULL(TERAPI, `0)` AS TOTAL 
FROM (`cm_reg__`, (SELECT g_sr1301.*, `cm_reg__`.`ASR` AS `ASU`, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN UT LIKE '1%' OR UT LIKE '2%' OR UT LIKE '5%' OR UT LIKE '6%' OR UT LIKE '8%' OR (UT BETWEEN '02' AND '09') OR (UT BETWEEN '36' AND '37') THEN `CHG` END) AS `TINDAKAN`, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN UT BETWEEN 31 AND 34 THEN `CHG` END) AS `PENUNJANG`, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN UT = 01 THEN `CHG` END) AS `IGD`, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN UT = 30 THEN `CHG` END) AS `TERAPI` 
    FROM g_sr1301 
    JOIN cm_reg__ ON g_sr1301.CREG = cm_reg__.`NO` 
    GROUP BY CREG ) AS tabelbiaya) 
JOIN `c_pst` ON `cm_reg__`.`CM` = `c_pst`.`CM` 
JOIN `rm_dgs` ON `cm_reg__`.`NO` = `rm_dgs`.`REGISTER` 
WHERE `cm_reg__`.`TGL` BETWEEN '2013-01-02' AND '2013-01-02' AND `cm_reg__`.`ASR` = 'ak' AND `cm_reg__`.`DOUT` > cm_reg__.TGL 
GROUP BY `NO` ORDER BY `TGL` ASC
```

All I want to expect is a table like this:

```
 ------- --------        --------------- --------------- --------- ------------ -----------
!CREG   !  TGL   ! ...  !CF1 (TINDAKAN) !CF2(PENUNJANG) !CF3(IGD) !CF4(TERAPI) !CF5(TOTAL) !
!-------!--------!      !---------------!---------------!---------!------------!-----------!
! ..    !  ..    ! ...  ! ..            ! ..            !  ..     ! ..         ! ..        !
!-------!--------!      !---------------!---------------!---------!------------!-----------!
```

Note that CF is Custom Field resulted from SUM.

Nah, after i run the query it result some warning:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM (`cm_reg__`, (SELECT g_sr1301.*, `cm_reg__`.`ASR` AS `ASU`, 
        SUM(CASE W' at line 2
```

Anyone can help me? As i am a new rookie in MySQL. Thanks before. :)

**UPDATE:**
Actually i make this query to work on Codeigniter model. I just realize that the problem is come from the backticks that suddenly appear in `IFNULL` line:

```
IFNULL(TINDAKAN, `0)` + IFNULL(PENUNJANG, `0)` + IFNULL(IGD, `0)` + IFNULL(TERAPI, `0)`
```

Then i just tricked the activerecord on CI to 'throw off' that backticks.
Ofcourse, solution from @PM77 below may works to...

The worked query is as mentioned form @NoDisplayName. I've try it and thats working. But the process is so long... Maybe its come from the joinned table.

Comment: This is invalid SQL syntax. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Syntax highlighting seems to make it somewhat obvious that all your `IFNULL`s are not correct.

Comment: Yeah, i know @PM77-1 that's why i make this question. Maybe you could more specific where is that invalid syntax?

Comment: `FROM ( database, (subquery) alias )` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: oh, i see. Thanks for the notice. I've try @NoDisplayName solution and it works but it took so long time to display the result, it take time around 29 seconds! Maybe there's any alternative solution? Especially about the JOIN syntax, i think the main time-consuming problem is from there.

Comment: a query this complicated is sometimes indicative of appallingly poor design

Answer (score 1):

If am not wrong this is what you need.

Remove the open bracket before `cm_reg__` in

`...'FROM (cm_reg__, (SELECT g_sr1301.*, cm_reg__.ASR AS ASU,`

and remove the close bracket after `tabelbiaya` in  `... AS tabelbiaya)`. Change comma to `cross join`. Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT cm_reg__.TGL,
                cm_reg__.JAM,
                cm_reg__.ASR,
                cm_reg__.CM,
                c_pst.NAMA,
                c_pst.SEX,
                c_pst.AGAMA,
                c_pst.EDU,
                c_pst.PKJ,
                c_pst.ALAMAT,
                c_pst.WILAYAH,
                cm_reg__.UMUR,
                cm_reg__.ASAL,
                cm_reg__.NO,
                cm_reg__.DR,
                rm_dgs.UT,
                cm_reg__.DOUT,
                c_pst.C_KELUARGA,
                TINDAKAN,
                PENUNJANG,
                IGD,
                TERAPI,
                Ifnull(TINDAKAN, 0) + Ifnull(PENUNJANG, 0)
                + Ifnull(IGD, 0) + Ifnull(TERAPI, 0) AS TOTAL
FROM   cm_reg__
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT g_sr1301.*,
                          cm_reg__.ASR AS ASU,
                          Sum(CASE
                                WHEN UT LIKE '1%'
                                      OR UT LIKE '2%'
                                      OR UT LIKE '5%'
                                      OR UT LIKE '6%'
                                      OR UT LIKE '8%'
                                      OR ( UT BETWEEN '02' AND '09' )
                                      OR ( UT BETWEEN '36' AND '37' ) THEN CHG
                              END)     AS TINDAKAN,
                          Sum(CASE
                                WHEN UT BETWEEN 31 AND 34 THEN CHG
                              END)     AS PENUNJANG,
                          Sum(CASE
                                WHEN UT = 01 THEN CHG
                              END)     AS IGD,
                          Sum(CASE
                                WHEN UT = 30 THEN CHG
                              END)     AS TERAPI
                   FROM   g_sr1301
                          JOIN cm_reg__
                            ON g_sr1301.CREG = cm_reg__.NO
                   GROUP  BY CREG) AS tabelbiaya
       JOIN c_pst
         ON cm_reg__.CM = c_pst.CM
       JOIN rm_dgs
         ON cm_reg__.NO = rm_dgs.REGISTER
WHERE  cm_reg__.TGL BETWEEN '2013-01-02' AND '2013-01-02'
       AND cm_reg__.ASR = 'ak'
       AND cm_reg__.DOUT > cm_reg__.TGL
GROUP  BY NO
ORDER  BY TGL ASC
```

Comment: Hey, thanks dude. I've try your solution and it works! But it took so long time to display the result, it take time around 29 seconds! Maybe there's any alternative solution? Especially about the JOIN syntax, i think the main time-consuming problem is from there.

Comment: @psikoplak: Using CROSS JOIN is usually a signal of impending performance problems.  Why do you want a CROSS JOIN?

Comment: it's actually simple, i just want to view some field from (unfotunately) many tables (obviously it consists of 4 tables: cm_reg__, c_pst, rm_dgs, and g_sr1301). The first 3 tables are to show basic data that just take some necessary fields. The process start to slow down when I joinning g_sr1301 tables. It is important, because this table contain `CHG` field to summarize, and set the summarized value to Custom Field, except `TOTAL`. Pheww... not so simple explanation to tell simple process. :D